# IIS Express 8 takes minutes to serve files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 project that I run on IIS Express when debugging. A few days ago, when I installed VS2012, IIS Express suddenly started to take veeeeery long time to serve every single file (JS files, CSS files). Our view has about a dozen of JS files. A force-refresh (Ctrl+F5) in the browser causes it to wait 4 minutes until the page is fully loaded. In the developer tools I can see that there is progress, but every single file takes a multitude of seconds until it is received.

It seems that VS2012 installed IIS Express 8. I had 7.5 before. Is this performance issue a known issue with IIS Express 8? My googling was not successful so far. Does anybody know anything related to it?

**Update:** I can confirm that by uninstalling 8, removing the MyDocuments\IISExpress directory, and installing 7.5, I can resolve the issue. A colleague of mine has had the same issue: After installing VS2012, which upgraded his IIS Express installation, it took him 4 minutes to load our web app's page.

Comment: Have you installed anything else at the same time as VS2012? antivirus, etc

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem in VS2013 and VS2015 right now.

Comment: @Alexander, I didn't. We switched to a full local IIS installation instead of "IIS Express"